# Equations of bisectors of two lines

Tags: vector-spaces

**Problem:**

The lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ have vector equations

$$\mathbf r_1= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
3 \\
\end{pmatrix} +\lambda
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\mathbf r_2= 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
4 \\
5 \\
\end{pmatrix} +\mu
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Find the equations of the two bisector lines between $l_1$ and $l_2$.

**My attempt:**
To find the intersection coordinates:

$$1+2\lambda=4+\mu$$
$$4+\lambda=4+2\mu$$
$$3+2\lambda=5+2\mu$$

Solving the above, I obtained $\lambda=2$ and $\mu=1$. Therefore the intersection point is:

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
3 \\
\end{pmatrix}+2
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I then make sure that the two direction vectors have the same length (magnitude):

$$\mathbf d_1=\sqrt {2^2+1^2+2^2}=3$$
$$\mathbf d_2=\sqrt {1^2+2^2+2^2}=3$$

And
$$\mathbf d_1+ \mathbf d_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
3 \\
4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\mathbf d_1- \mathbf d_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And hence the equations of the two bisector lines are:

$$
\mathbf b_1=\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
\end{pmatrix}+\alpha
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
3 \\
4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf b_2=\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
\end{pmatrix}+\beta
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And I expect that $\mathbf b_2$ lies on the $xy$ plane since the $z$ component of its direction vector is $0$.

I then plot $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$, and $\mathbf b_1$ and $\mathbf b_1$ in Desmos 3D beta and found that $\mathbf b_2$ does not bisect $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$ (see image).

[image]

The blue line is $\mathbf b_2$ and from the image, it is obvious that it does not bisect the $l_1$ and $l_2$.

**Question:**

What have I done wrong for $\mathbf b_2$?

Thank you.

Comment: But $\mathbf b_2$ passes through $(5,6,7)$, so not entirely on the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @peterwhy thank you. Then what is wrong with my graph? Is my solution for $\mathbf b_2$ correct?

Comment: What's wrong with the graph is... that the blue line is on the $xy$-plane and not through $(5,6,7)$, I suppose? I wonder if the "Extend to 3D" checkbox will show the full plane perpendicular to the $xy$-plane. I have not checked the full calculations for $\mathbf b_2$.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, after clicking on the "Extend to 3D", the plane extends up to $(5,6,7)$

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning and equations are all correct!

The line $ \bf b_2$ is parallel to the $xy$ plane but goes thru the point $(5,6,7)$.  Hence this line sits 7 units above the $xy$ plane.

Here is a way to graph parametric equations in Desmos.  As $\beta$ (called $t$ in the linked Desmos) varies from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ your equation traces out the line $\bf b_2$.

https://www.desmos.com/3d/296d5afae4

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.